# Warning: file_put_contents(invoice-1574071311.pdf): failed to open stream: Read-only file system in file/path/Test.php on line 100

Tags: magento2, pdf, magento2-cloud, download, invoice-pdf

Facing error while downloading the pdf file from the frontend link on the cloud server

**Warning: file_put_contents(invoice-1574071311.pdf): failed to open stream: Read-only file system in file/path/Test.php on line 100**

Comment: It means that you do not have write permissions on this folder, also file_put_contents needs a second parameter with the contents.

Comment: It means that you do not have write permissions on this folder, also file_put_contents needs a second parameter with the contents.

Comment: @pontikos yes I've added content as a second argument but how can I download files with the Read-only folder?

Comment: You should put the contents in pub/media not where your class is.